# User selectable CSS color schemes with cookie support

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cookies

I'm building a website template for primarily text content.

I would like to have two user switchable color schemes.

One dark background/light text and one light background/dark text to suit different viewing conditions.

How do I plan and design it such that user can toggle color scheme with a click of button and have cookie memorize the user's preference?

Without breaking the design, I would also like to let the user be able to increase the font-size and line-height for certain content block, eg. `<div id="article"></font>`

Is this feasible?

Comment: What have you though about? Is there any code you can show us?

Comment: I'm at the planning stage.  My thought was to use cookie to memorize user's preference. Using a javascript/jquery link/button to toggle CSS for text/background/link colors.  The javascript part is what I'm not familiar with.  I don't have any code yet, just simple `body { color:black; background:white; } a { color:blue }` to begin with, I'm building everything from scratch on a blank canvas.

Comment: What I would do is making a shared class between multiple files and choose a load a CSS file with the different types of colors. so you would have `blue-stylesheet.css` and `pink-stylesheet.css` and they both have a class of `user-selected-color` for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@GamerNebulae @EliTownsend After studying the answer and making some modification, I come up with a solution that works for my situation.

Not sure if it's heavy when it comes to execution.  Any advice for further improvement is appreciated.

**CSS**

```
body.dark {
    background: #222;
    color: #777;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" onclick="changeTheme()">Switch</a>
```

**Javscript**

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name,"",-1);
}

function changeTheme() {
    if (jQuery("body").hasClass("dark")) {
        jQuery("body").removeClass("dark");
        createCookie('theme', 'regular', 7);
    }
    else {
        jQuery("body").addClass("dark");
        createCookie('theme', 'dark', 7);
    }
}

// initialize page, apply theme color by checking cookie variable 'theme'
var theme = readCookie('theme');
if(theme == "dark") jQuery("body").addClass("dark");
else if (theme == "regular") jQuery("body").removeClass("dark");
else if (jQuery("body").hasClass("dark")) createCookie('theme', 'dark', 7);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Stylesheets**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" title="blue" href="http://example.com/css/blue.css">
<link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" title="pink" href="http://example.com/css/pink.css">
```

**HTML**

```
<form>
<input type="submit" onclick="switch_style('blue');return false;" name="theme" value="Blue Theme" id="blue">
<input type="submit" onclick="switch_style('pink');return false;" name="theme" value="Pink Theme" id="pink">
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
//TO BE CUSTOMISED

var style_cookie_name = "style" ;
var style_cookie_duration = 30 ;
var style_domain = "thesitewizard.com" ;

// END OF CUSTOMISABLE SECTION
// You do not need to customise anything below this line

function switch_style ( css_title )
{
// You may use this script on your site free of charge provided
// you do not remove this notice or the URL below. Script from
// http://www.thesitewizard.com/javascripts/change-style-sheets.shtml
  var i, link_tag ;
  for (i = 0, link_tag = document.getElementsByTagName("link") ;
    i < link_tag.length ; i++ ) {
    if ((link_tag[i].rel.indexOf( "stylesheet" ) != -1) &&
      link_tag[i].title) {
      link_tag[i].disabled = true ;
      if (link_tag[i].title == css_title) {
        link_tag[i].disabled = false ;
      }
    }
    set_cookie( style_cookie_name, css_title,
      style_cookie_duration, style_domain );
  }
}
function set_style_from_cookie()
{
  var css_title = get_cookie( style_cookie_name );
  if (css_title.length) {
    switch_style( css_title );
  }
}
function set_cookie ( cookie_name, cookie_value,
    lifespan_in_days, valid_domain )
{
    // http://www.thesitewizard.com/javascripts/cookies.shtml
    var domain_string = valid_domain ?
                       ("; domain=" + valid_domain) : '' ;
    document.cookie = cookie_name +
                       "=" + encodeURIComponent( cookie_value ) +
                       "; max-age=" + 60 * 60 *
                       24 * lifespan_in_days +
                       "; path=/" + domain_string ;
}
function get_cookie ( cookie_name )
{
    // http://www.thesitewizard.com/javascripts/cookies.shtml
    var cookie_string = document.cookie ;
    if (cookie_string.length != 0) {
        var cookie_value = cookie_string.match (
                        '(^|;)[\s]*' +
                        cookie_name +
                        '=([^;]*)' );
        return decodeURIComponent ( cookie_value[2] ) ;
    }
    return '' ;
}
```

I found this located here [How to Use Javascript to Change a CSS](http://www.thesitewizard.com/javascripts/change-style-sheets.shtml)

Comment: This is very heavy once you need this for the whole page. Furthermore, it's not very programmer-friendly.